# Seaborn Heatmap Custom colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

Hi i just created custom cmap for seaborn heatmap but when i want to use it, it do not show correct color. I've done step by step :

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matrix = np.array([[149030, 34],[7442, 12]])
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(matrix.min(), matrix.max())
boundaries = [value for value in matrix.flatten().tolist()]
list.sort(boundaries)

colors = [[norm(boundaries[0]), "#90AFC5"], 
          [norm(boundaries[1]), "#336B87"], 
          [norm(boundaries[2]), "#2a3132"], 
          [norm(boundaries[3]), "#763626"]]
    
    
cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", colors)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = plt.subplot() 
    

annot = np.array([[f"{matrix[0,0]}", f"{matrix[0,1]}"],
                  [f"{matrix[1,0]}", f"{matrix[1,1]}"]], dtype=object)    

sns.heatmap(matrix,
            annot=annot,
            annot_kws={"size": 11},
            fmt="",
            ax=ax,
            vmin=matrix.min(),
            vmax=matrix.max(),
            cmap=cmap,
            cbar=True,
            cbar_kws={'format': '%.0f%%', 'ticks': boundaries, 'drawedges': True},
            xticklabels=False,
            yticklabels=False)
```

My output as you can see there are two blue columns, but I have defined different colors:

[image: As you can see there is two blue column]

Comment: I think the heatmap is correct. The problem is the scale of the numbers too vast. Try to normalize the numbers first, then the color difference will be more visible.

Answer (score 9):

If you use a [`BoundaryNorm`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm.html), you can give colors for the ranges **between** the boundaries. To get 4 ranges, you need 5 boundaries.  One approach is to add one extra boundary at the end. In the question it is unclear what you want to do with colorvalues that don't coincide with a boundary. In the code below, the color is used for a boundary value and the range up till the next boundary.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matrix = np.array([[149030, 34], [7442, 12]])
boundaries = [value for value in matrix.flatten().tolist()]
list.sort(boundaries)
colors = ["#90AFC5", "#336B87", "#2a3132", "#763626"]
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries=boundaries + [boundaries[-1]], ncolors=256)

cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", colors)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = plt.subplot()

annot = np.array([[f"{matrix[0, 0]}", f"{matrix[0, 1]}"],
                  [f"{matrix[1, 0]}", f"{matrix[1, 1]}"]], dtype=object)

sns.heatmap(matrix,
            annot=annot,
            annot_kws={"size": 11},
            fmt="",
            ax=ax,
            cmap=cmap,
            norm=norm,
            cbar=True,
            cbar_kws={'format': '%.0f%%', 'ticks': boundaries, 'drawedges': True},
            xticklabels=False,
            yticklabels=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thank you so much, that is what i want.